# Symfony2 translator - domain from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I'm gonna explain what I'm trying to achieve:

I have one bundle, let's say **BundleA** and another one called **BundleB**, both with his translation files. Also, both have a translation file called **mytranslations**

> BundleA -> mytranslations -> mykey: 'My translated text'
>
> BundleB -> mytranslations -> mykey: 'Another translated text'

Now, if I try to translate from that file on my **BundleA**, on a controller for example, I'll do something like this:

```
$translator->trans('mykey', array(), 'mytranslations');
```

and I will get: **My translated text**

If I do it on my **BundleB**, I'll do:

```
$translator->trans('mykey', array(), 'mytranslations');
```

and I will get: **Another translated text**

What I want to achieve is to use that translator from **BundleA** but to get the translated text from **BundleB**, so in **BundleA** I'll do:

```
$translator->trans('mykey', array(), 'mytranslations');
```

and I get: **Another translated text**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers!